# Transfer Files from phone to computer via network (one side transfer)

Tags: c#, winforms, share

i'm new in programming, i have a phone and pc(not a labtop) they are both on the same HomeNetwork, my idea is that i want to open a specific ip address on my phone which will display a page where i can choose to send any type of information like pictures or files then i choose the file i want to send.

on the pc, a dialogue would appear to accept or decline the transfer, and the files should be saved in a specific folder with the phone name that transferred the files to the pc. then my winform app will display the folder and it contents in the way i desire.

so far,I have only created the application that will read the folder name and its contents in the desired way. i dont have a clue how does transferring works or what kind of language will i need to learn. I tried searching google but it didnt help at all, i have basic knowledge of HTML and CSS and i'm kind good in C# and basic knowledge in SQl.

please i need the first lead, not the whole code, its all what i'm asking for.

Comment: If your device is recognized as WPD, you need [IFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation)'s `CopyItem`(s) / `MoveItem`(s) methods, plus [SHGetKnownFolderItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderitem) and a File Dialog created with [FOS_FORCESHOWHIDDEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-_fileopendialogoptions) (and, IIRC, `FOS_NODEREFERENCELINKS`) (so you can select files / folder of the WPD)

Comment: Probably the simplest method is to use a USB cable between phone and machine.  If you are going to transfer over HTTP than you need a webpage on PC and send a request from phone to PC to do an upload.  So it would be an ASP.Net type program.  You request can send on file at a time in the body of the message or at MIME attachments (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)).  You could also zip files and send the zip files from phone to PC.  Also you could use FTP to upload files.

Comment: [MediaDevices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaDevices)